# IT Guy meal plan

Tags: meal-plan

I was skinny and worked out(3 days a week) and ate a lot, became fat and then came back in shape(but bulged out tummy, I don't know how I shrinked, but left gym and hence a change in meal plan) , i.e. not skinny, but  not a big beast either. I started gym again(now 5 days a week) and below, I am sharing my meal plan ,
Please suggest alternatives if any

- 7:00 AM wake up
- 8:00 AM 50 gms of cheese
- 8:45 AM Prauntha (fried wheat chapati with stuffed potato and onion)
- 11:00 AM banana shake and a patty
- 1:00 PM Gym
- 2:15 PM Protein Shake
- 3:30 PM Banana shake
- 5:00 PM some random food
- 6:30 PM glass of Mix juice
- 7:30 PM Street food (chicken burger)
- 9:00 PM wheat chapatis

  I want stamina, I want strength, I want to look big.

Even half of the following image will do for me,

[image]

and I am like this right now, with a little tummy hanging out,

[image]

Comment: "I want to look big" Look big meaning? Look big like Olympic athletes or like Mr. Olympia competitors?

Comment: @PravinCG No , I am not that tall, just 5'5. i wanted to be  muscular, ripped, my T-shirt must be wrapped around my muscles and chest broad, like the Captain America guy

Comment: A lot of sugar/carbs calories in your diet.

Comment: What you are describing requires a multi-year plan with an enormous amount of variables. No one can give you a specific answer to that. Why don't you set yourself a more attainable goal that you can define SMART? Like a weight/fat percentage/waist circumference goal? Or a strength goal? Or something like 'add half an inch to biceps without gaining fat'.

Comment: Voting to close as the question is too broad. Other than that, hire a personal trainer who can sort out your diet and routine. Do what he says exactly and commit to it 100% for 2 years, then come back and ask more specific questions

Comment: @DennisHaarbrink That would be excellent, but you know what will drive me more?  to see some positive results when i hit the Gym , to be able to pick more weight every week as compared to last week. I am ready to spent years and to be patient. Just need someone to alter my routine as mentioned above. 100%... in gym, in meal, in everything for the fitness .

Comment: @DarkHippo that was blunt and I respect blunt opinions coz only they can bring out best, I know that it will take a lot of hard work and patience, Now i am earning enough to eat and get a good diet, but i want someone to alter and schedule my day as i explained above. Knidly go through the list and tell me what should be replaced and what must be added.

Comment: @Anonymous that's exactly what I said. At this stage, it really doesn't matter much what you do. Make sure you are in a slight surplus of calories, get your proteins and fatties in. Go hard at the gym, and eat/sleep well outside of the gym. You will see plenty of progress.

Comment: I second @DarkHippo 's vote to close this. If you want answers on this board I suggest you break this post up and create separate topics.

Comment: @MJB Guys, I respect your opinion to vote to close this, but can we be littlE flexible. This website is still in beta, let it flourish. Just guide new users to ask questions the way you want on the place of voting them for close. You can use your previllege later, when this website will have a great number of users(Saying this because i have seen a lot of users loosing their interest from stackoverflow platform for the same).

Comment: 1. make sure you get at least 8 hours of sleep a night, 2. drink enough water (how much depends on your bodyweight, but about 1lt per 25kg bodyweight, rounding up) 3. eat 1g protein per lb of bodyweight, 4. pick a training routine and stick to it for at least 6 months, which one isn't that important, but I'd say Starting Strength or StrongLifts. After that, switch to 5/3/1 and stick at that for the next 18 months, 5. you'll suffer setbacks, accept them and get back on it as soon as you can, don't dwell on them.

Comment: @DarkHippo thanksss a lot for these words of widsom.

Answer (score 2):

Start with either StrongLifts 5x5 or Starting strength for linear progression. Every session/week you need to progressively overload thereby increasing the strength and it is quantifiable progress that you can measure.

Highly recommend to start with just the barbell (45 pounds in case of olympic bar) and then add weights to it progressively. The lighter load initially will help you perfect the form and also condition your body for strength gain in the coming weeks and months.

The above done for a period of 6-12 months will make you strong and help you move 1.5x-2.0x weight which should be a very respectable goal.

As far as meal plan is concerned, it looks okie to me.